# Running multiple queries in PHP insert erroneous values

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have run into a problem I have never seen before. The code is too much and large and too many classes, so pardon me for not going into much detail.
The interesting bit is this:

```
$copy = clone $this;
$copy->workerid = $new_workerid;
if ( $copy->mysql_create_row( $this->pending_table ) )
    return $copy;
```

This runs as expected. When I go into the database, I see a new entry in table Pending.

When however I run multiple queries in succession:

```
$copy = clone $this;
$copy->workerid = $new_workerid;
if ( $copy->mysql_create_row( $this->pending_table ) )
    if ( $this->mysql_delete_row( $this->pending_table ) )
        if ( $this->mysql_create_row( $this->cancelled_table ) )
            return $copy;
```

Then for some unexplainable reason, the wrong id column is inserted at one of the tables.
In specific method $copy->mysql_create_row, among other things, does this:

```
if ( $con = db_connect() ) {
    $res = mysqli_query( $con, "INSERT INTO $table (`workerid`,`time`,`location`,`tasks`) VALUES ('$this->workerid','$this->datetime','$this->location','$this->tasks');" ) 
    or error_log( "mysql_create_row Error: " . mysqli_error( $con ) );
    if ( $res ) {
        $this->contactid = mysqli_insert_id( $con );
        foreach ( $this->attendees as $att ) {
            $att->__setContactId( $this->contactid );
            if ( !$att->mysql_create_row( $this->attendee_table ) ) {
                error_log( " Contact->mysql_create_row Error: Did not create attendee MySQL row" );
                return false;
            }
```

Delegation through object method $att->mysql_create_row( $this->attendee_table ) works the same way, it is merely an INSERT query.

Now this is where the things make no sense:
Whereas the newly inserted $copy object inserts the correct id at $copy->mysql_create_row, the $att->mysql_create_row does not !!!
It inserts the old id.
Furthermore, when I echo out the query from $att->mysql_create_row, it echoes out the correct (new id)!!!

But when I go into the actual database, it has inserted the old id. This makes absolutely no sense to me.

I have tried to create custom __clone() methods, try to make sure that I have copies and not references (damn you php) but it still produces the same error.

The problem seems to be with the successive queries, as when I do not do the delete or the new insert, I do not have any problems.

The delete works fine, and the second insertion also works fine, without any errors whatsoever.

What could possibly force the MySQLi api to insert the wrong id, while the query echoes the correct one ?
I could only thing of some form of background/multithreaded corruption, but since I have no control over this sort of thing, I do not even know how to tackle the problem.

When echoing out the query from $att->mysql_create_row, I get:

before query id: 305

> 'INSERT INTO `XXXXXXXX`.`attendees`
>    (`contactid`,`title`,`forenames`,`surname`,`relationship`,`gender`,`age`,`arrived`,`left`,`supervised`,`ics_number`)
>   VALUES ('305','Mr',
>   'Alex','Werner','','M','29/08/1981','0','','','0');'

after query id: 305

But when I actually go into the database, the value inserted is the old id value (say 294).
The table column is not Auto-incrementing, is not unique or primary, it is simply a int(11).

What on earth could be causing this ?

Comment: Use prepared statements (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) insetead of `mysqli::query` to avoid SQL Injections!

Comment: @Misch How is that different ? Should I be using it everywhere where the are multiple queries to be run successively ?

Comment: No, you should use it everywhere where user data can be inserted (probably almost anywhere). Assume this query: "SELECT * FROM t WHERE value='$variable'". Now if a malicious user enters: "'; DROP TABLE t; --", the resulting query will be: "SELECT * FROM t WHERE value=''; DROP TABLE t --'". Prepared statements prevent this.

Comment: You may also want to read this answer, it explains SQL Injections really good: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/25710/17060

Comment: Nope, it did nothing, exact same problem is still there.

Comment: No, this was not thought to solve this problem. It is thought to prevent SQL Injections, which are independent of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem could be that you are using `mysql_last_insert_id` to get the id of the last inserted row. As you are inserting multiple rows, it could be possible that you don't get the correct id.

Replace `mysql_last_insert_id` call with a `select` query that returns the id of your last insertion and look if your problem is solved.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I figured it out an hour ago when I run into a similar problem. Its important to note the sequence in which those queries are called. I thought that by clone, I would get a deep copy, turns out I am still referencing the same object of object (attendee is an object within an array of contact).